# Doctrine query with subquery doesn't work

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I use Symfony 4 and Doctrine, I want to make a complexe query with a subquery :

```
    $status = [0, 1];

    $subquery = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('COUNT(item.id)')
        ->from('App\Entity\CalculItem', 'item')
        ->where('item.status IN (:status)')
        ->andWhere('item.file = c')
        ->setParameter('status', $status)
        ->getDQL();

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('c.status = :status')
        ->setParameter('status', 1)
        ->andWhere('('. $subquery .') = 0')
        ->andWhere('c.stat_items > 0')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ;
    dump($query->getSQL());

    return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
```

I don't have errors, but it returns me a result while I don't expect any result. If I use the `->getSQL()` directly in phpmyadmin, I don't have any result.

I don't understand why I have a result returned with the "Symfony / Doctrine way", and no result with the SQL query ?

**EDIT**

If you use a subquery, you need to bound the params only in the "master" query. Since you use `->getDQL()` for the subquery, it doesn't bound the params.

In my case, I used (my mistake) `:status` params for both queries.

Comment: there is no need to dump the sql query, you can get it n the profiler. If you don't replace the params and execute directly the request found in the profiler, what is the result ?

Comment: Oh you are a genius, I never think about using the profiler for sql queries, I forgot how powerful it is. The `status` is not considerated as an array, here is the mistake..